# Qt creator настройка

Tags: qtcreator

Только установил Qt Creator, при установке выбирал следующие пункты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попытка создать консольное приложение (проверка все ли работает)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как исправить ошибку

Comment: Никогда не пользовался на виндовс.. но вроде бы вам нужно установить https://cmake.org/download/

Comment: [! [https://pp.userapi.com/c841538/v841538711/75e88/g_dzz64hrXI.jpg ][1]][1] установил cmake, в настройках кьюта он отображается, не уверен, возможно что он был и до этого, просто я не заглядывал сюда, все еще не работает

Comment: установка cmake помогла. спасибо